# how to setValue and getValue from ComboBoxCell in sencha gxt3?

Tags: java, gwt, gxt

I have Setted a ComboBoxCell to a column in grid, and then i cannot do get value and set value to this ComboBoxCell.

Comment: Can you please share the code which you have tried so far ?